# How to pass AsyncResult generated to other API in FastAPI python

Tags: python-3.x, fastapi

Currently I trying to develop 2 APIs in FastAPI python, one which submits jobs asynchronously and other Get API which on request replies you current status of job completed. Please help me achieve this or any other standard way around through which I can utilize AsyncResult object created in object. Please refer code below.

```
   def worker(x):
       #perform computation

   # POST API which starts job
   @app.post("/jobs/", status_code=HTTP_201_CREATED)
   async def create_job():
       pool = Pool(processes=4)
       #generating iterable
       list_data = get_data()      
       result = pool.map_async(worker, list_data)
       return result

    # GET API to check whether job running in multiprocessing is complete or not
    @app.get("/status")
    def read_job(id: str):
       #want to use result object(multiprocessing.pool.AsyncResult) and show status of job performed
       if result.get() == 1:
           return {"success":True}
       return {"success":False}
```

Answer (score 0):

If my understanding of what you are trying to do is correct, and get_data() is a coroutine method, then you should be able to just await and return that get_data() method.  Most of the hard parts with managing loops should in most cases be handled by FastAPI.

```
  @app.post("/jobs/", status_code=HTTP_201_CREATED)
  async def create_job():
     return await get_data()
```

Async and multiprocessing aren't the same thing though.  And you don't really need to be dealing with multiprocessing inside of FastAPI.  If it's not a coroutine, you should just keep the whole method synchronous, or figure out what you need to do to make the get_data() method into a coroutine method.

More information on how to do this in Python 3.8 can be found here:  https://www.integralist.co.uk/posts/python-asyncio/

Comment: Thanks for reply. To be honest, I am new to asyncio package in python. But main aim to develop 2 api, one on which we can submit jobs( which will use multiprocessing to achieve the task ) and other api to get status of submitted jobs ( so I want to utilize AsynResult object generated on first api to send the status of job). Can you suggest any other model or approach to achieve this. Thanks